# Restrict Customer's View of Object Records to Only Those They Create

Tags: security, portal, record

I need to create a force.com portal site in which customers can submit one or two employment applications which they will fill out online in the site.

The challenge for me (as a new force.com developer) is how to allow creation of the new record on the application object by a customer while at the same time restricting the customer's view to only the applications they've submitted.

Does force.com provide an out of the box way to achieve this, or will I need to work out my own method?  Is there a good resource to guide me in the right direction?  Can someone provide an example code snippit showing how to restrict a customer's view to the records they've submitted to the portal through an online form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked into any of the security documentation about the platform yet? Organization wide defaults will dictate how locked down your object model is, so you'll want to ensure that that particular object type is set to Private.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=admin_sharing.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Setting the object to private ensured that only the creator of the object can see it.  Using organization wide defaults will allow me to specify who (in the organization hierarchy) can see the private records.  It appears that I could also have used default sharing rules to specify more fine grain permissions on the object.

Comment: OWD is basically defining how locked down you want each object's records to be, and then things like sharing rules, profile access, etc will start to open up access.